# Postfix as SMTP server for Gmail. ("Send mail as" google option)

Tags: debian, ssl, postfix, smtp, gmail

I have a vps on ovh.com runing debian 7. I want to set up my gmail account to send, and recieve mail on (for example) myname@example.com address. I searched google for hours and couldn't find a solution to my problem. I need a tutorial on how to set it up.

I've already configured postfix to forward mails sent to myname@example.com using [this guide](http://www.binarytides.com/postfix-mail-forwarding-debian/).

I receive mails, but they're unencrypted. Gmail displays a warning saying that ip-xxx-xx-xx.net (ovh provided i guess) did not encrypt this message. It seems that i have tls not configured.

My domain is configured as it should (i think) - example.com MX pointing at mail.example.com and mail.example.com A pointing at myserverip.

I tried to add smtp server to google (send mail as) and it sees the server on port 25 (postfix default) but it displays error:

`Authentication failed. Please check your username/password.
[Server response: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure code(535)`

So i need a tutorial which will guide me on how to set up postfix as SMTP server that i can add to my gmail account, so i can send emails from gmail using my alias (myname.example.com), receive on this adress with encryption.

**UPDATE**

I changed something and it seems like there is some authentication error.
Google greets me with something like this :

> Authentication failed. Please check your username/password.
>   [Server response: Unspecified Error (SENT_SECOND_EHLO): Smtp server does not advertise AUTH capability code(0) ]

Comment: I'm having the same problem. There are plenty of posts about using Gmail as an SMTP server, but nothing for this. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to main.cf and restart the postfix

```
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
```

For debugging you can use

```
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
```

Comment: I added this, and now it seems like i don't have some kind of EHLO encription or something.

Comment: It would be great if you add some postfix log

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. My logs look like this (stripped out dates, times, ips):
connect from mail-ua1-f41.google.com
Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-ua1-f41.google.com: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (128/128 bits)
warning: mail-ua1-f41.google.com: SASL PLAIN authentication failed:
lost connection after AUTH from mail-ua1-f41.google.com
disconnect from mail-ua1-f41.google.com ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=0/1 commands=3/4

Answer (score 0):

All things being equal. I think what you want to do is offered by Google.

Second. This, I think, is one of the easier to follow Postfix guides: 
https://workaround.org/ispmail/wheezy/   <- Deb 7
https://workaround.org/ispmail/jessie    <- Deb 8

That should get you a start. From there Google, man pages, & such are your friend.